# Creating light animations for rgb led arduino

Tags: animation, arduino, led

I'm making an arduino controlled lamp with rgb. I'm trying to add smooth transistion between each color which would be shone from the led. I don't want the channels to be animated separately. At the moment it only works with one channel at a time and transistions only work when the brightness is increasing.

```
    const int redpin = 9;
    const int greenpin = 10;
    const int bluepin = 11;
    int currRed = 0;
    int currGreen = 0;
    int currBlue = 0;
    int dur = 1000;

    void setup() {
      pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
      if (Serial.available()) {
      int red = Serial.parseInt();
      int green = Serial.parseInt();
      int blue = Serial.parseInt();

      if (Serial.read() == '\n') {
        red = constrain(red, 0, 255);
        green = constrain(green, 0, 255);
        blue = constrain(blue, 0, 255);
        }

      updateRGBfade(redpin, red, dur, currRed);
      updateRGBfade(greenpin, green, dur, currGreen);
      updateRGBfade(bluepin, blue, dur, currBlue);
      }
    }



   void updateRGBfade(int pin, int col, int animdur, int currcol) {
      if (col > currcol) {
        for (int setto = currcol; setto < col; setto++) {
          analogWrite(pin, setto);
          delay(5);
        }
      }
      if (col < currcol) {
        for (int setto = currcol; setto > col; setto=setto-1) {
          analogWrite(pin, setto);
          delay(5);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currcolors (currRed, currGreen and currBlue) seen constant and equal zero. So updateRGBfade functions run only first if block because currcol always zero and i think col is bigger then zero normally. So the function only run increase process. You can add follow lines in the functions if blocks bellow delay(5)s

```
if(pin == redpin){
currRed = currcol;
}else if(pin == greenpin){
currGreen = currcol;
}else if(pin == bluepin ){
currBlue = currcol;
}
```

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I have uploaded this code now, but it still works the same